# Optimization question on a function $(, , , ) = \min\{, 2\} + \max \{3, 4\}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, linear-programming, self-learning, utility

I have the following utility function

$$(, , , ) = \min\{, 2\} + \max \{3, 4\}$$

I want to find its demand function.

For that

$$\operatorname{Max}(, , , ) = \min\{, 2\} + \max \{3, 4\}$$

S.t.

$$p_1 x+p_2 y + p_3 z +p_4 w \le  I$$

But I cannot proceed from here. Please suggest a solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a variable $v$ to represent $\min\{x,2y\}$ and solve two linear programming problems:

1. Maximize $v+3z$ subject to
   \begin{align}
   v &\le x \\
   v &\le 2y \\
   3z &\ge 4w \\
   p_1 x + p_2 y + p_3 z + p_4 w &\le I \\
   \end{align}
2. Maximize $v+4w$ subject to
   \begin{align}
   v &\le x \\
   v &\le 2y \\
   3z &\le 4w \\
   p_1 x + p_2 y + p_3 z + p_4 w &\le I \\
   \end{align}

Take whichever solution yields the larger of the two resulting objective values.